# ArrayList in which I have an Array

Tags: java

I am working in a JSF project and I am trying to make an ArrayList in which I have an Array. But I can't understand why it does not work.

I have an error in this part -

```
private static final ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>(
                Arrays.asList(new User("A1", rights[0]), 
                             (new User("A2", rights[1])), 
                             (new User("A3", rights[1])), 
                             (new User("A4", rights[2])),
                             (new User("A5", rights[2]))));
```

I think I am doing this part wrongly : `(new User("A1", rights[0]),`

This is my code :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "user")
@SessionScoped
public class userDataBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * SERIAL UID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * ATTRIBUTS
     */
    private String name;
    private String[] rights= { "Administration", "Consultation",
            "Modification" };


    // GETTER AND SETTER
    // CONSTRUCTORS

    private static final ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>(
            Arrays.asList(new Utilisateur("A1", rights[0]), 
                         (new Utilisateur("A2", rights[1])), 
                         (new Utilisateur("A3", rights[1])), 
                         (new Utilisateur("A4", rights[2])),
                         (new Utilisateur("A5", rights[2]))));



    public ArrayList<User> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public String addAction() {
        User user = new User(this.name, this.rights);

        userList.add(user);

        return null;
    }

    public String deleteAction(User user) {
        userList.remove(user);
        return null;
    }

    public class User{

        String name;
        String[] rights;

        // GETTER AND SETTER

        public Utilisateur(String user, String[] rights) {
            this.name = name;
            this.rights = rights;
        }

        public Utilisateur() {
            super();
        }

    }

}
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field rights

Comment: Rather than a `private static final` array of Strings, this is probably a case for an `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error method states, a static context cannot access a non-static context. Since `userDataBean.rigthts` is essentially a constant, just add the `static` modifier and you should be fine. If you really want to convey the point that it should be treated as a constant, you could also declare it `final`

```
private static final String[] RIGHTS = { "Administration", "Consultation",
        "Modification" };

private static final ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>(
        Arrays.asList(new Utilisateur("A1", RIGHTS[0]), 
                     (new Utilisateur("A2", RIGHTS[1])), 
                     (new Utilisateur("A3", RIGHTS[1])), 
                     (new Utilisateur("A4", RIGHTS[2])),
                     (new Utilisateur("A5", RIGHTS[2]))));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `static` methods can access `static` data members but not the non-static counterpart. This is because the **scope** of `static` methods and fields are bound to the **class**, not the **objects** of the class. Non-static data members and methods on the other hand are scoped with instances of the class.

First, the classes are loaded into the jvm by a **ClassLoader**. Instantiating an object of the class then follows. This order cannot be changed.
In your case,

`private String[] rights= { "Administration", "Consultation", "Modification" };`

codeblock is executed on instantiating the userDataBean class and not before. On the other hand,

`private static final ArrayList<User> userList`

is instantiated as soon as the class `userDataBean` is loaded by the **ClassLoader**.

Going by the above design semantics, this is an error since `rights` member variable is not instantiated yet is being accessed from a static context, at the class load time.

Declaring the `rights` as static will solve the problem.

```
    private static String[] rights= { "Administration", "Consultation",
        "Modification" };
```